# Migrating from ADF to SSIS

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, etl, business-intelligence

I have been using the Azure Data Factory as the ETL tool but I would like to downgrade/migrate to the on-prem SSIS due to business decision. Is there a way to go about this except re-writing the pipelines? Maybe a lift and shift solution?

All the solutions I see is migrating from SSIS to ADF only.

Comment: No there isn't. SSIS is essentially abandoned with few if any new features since 2016. ADF isn't a newer version of SSIS, it only has an SSIS task to ease migration to Azure. `Maybe a lift and shift solution?` you're going the opposite way. Besides, `lift and shift` in this case would mean rewriting everything as SSIS packages that run on ADF. You still have to rewrite everything

Comment: Seems like an excellent answer @PanagiotisKanavos...

Comment: *Why* is ADF downgraded to SSIS? What are the goals? You need to know this so you can pick the correct technology. Is it the Azure subscription cost? The difficulty of uploading on-premise data to Azure? The need for version control? Lack of experience with ADF? Where is the data stored? If you have to *download* cloud data you'll end up paying for the outbound bandwidth

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the reason behind the move is reducing the costs.

Comment: What does the ETL actually do? Move data between databases, load CSVs, load a data warehouse? And where is the data stored? Azure or on-premise? All of this matters. You could replace ADF with BULK INSERT from Azure blobs for CSV loading for example. Or you could use a *different* service to query external data without loading it in the database

Comment: @SinahMolepo If your main issue is reducing costs, consider moving to use a self hosted integration runtime, which in some cases might save you money. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately there is no direct mapping/conversion tool between SSIS and ADF .As ADF is still a developing tool, not all features of SSIS are present within ADF and vice versa. You would have to manually reciprocate your add pipeline logic in ssis either via normal dataflow/control activities wherever possible or use script task to handle the non available ones.

Also in ADF, are you using dataflows or normal activities? Also, can you just privide the image of your overall ADF pipeline flow ? Source and sink etc as it may help us help you better